# Recovering estimated coefficient from the intercept when using multiple categorical variables?

Tags: regression, linear

I feel like I'm simply missing something in my reasoning here, so any help would be appreciated.

In a standard regression model with just one categorical variable:

$$ y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{a:d} $$

that has four levels - we would end up with three coefficient estimates (for levels $$b, c, d$$) with the coefficient for *a*  being rolled into the intercept. If I wanted to "recover" this coefficient estimate, I could just use a no-intercept model.

What about a case where we have multiple categorical variables?

$$ y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{a:d} + \beta_2x_{e:l} + \beta_3x{q_t} $$

In this situation (as I understand it) - multiple different reference levels are being rolled into the intercept. If I again wanted to just recover the estimated coefficient for *a*, how would I do so?

Comment: The process of answering this question has to begin by considering how you encoded the values of the categorical variables.  What coding method do you have in mind?

Comment: @whuber so it may be something like: x_1 may be "small", "medium", "tall" and x_2 might be "thin", "average", "wide" - things like that. I thought about whether or not one hot encoding would alleviate the problem but you'd still end up in a situation with linear separation (at least I think so).

Comment: There are infinitely many ways to encode categorical variables.  For instance, a binary variable might be assigned the values $0$ and $1$ or the values $-1$ and $1.$  A ternary variable might be assigned the values $(0,0),$ $(0,1),$ and $(1,0)$ or the values $(0,0,1),$ $(0,1,0),$ $(1,0,0)$ or the values $(1,1,1),$ $(1,-1,0),$ and $(2,-1,-1),$ for instance.  *The specific encoding determines how to interpret the coefficients.*